# graphviz - how to place subgraphs horizontally

Tags: graphviz

How can i place the following diagram with subgraphs layout horizontally, not vertically?

Up until now I had the understanding that `rankdir` parameter is responsible for that - and that's why I've set it to `LR`. However this does not work.

I've been trying to fiddle around with ratio options, but none of those tried gave anything useful.

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR
ratio="expand"
    subgraph cluster_3 {
        label=C
        style=filled
        color=lightgrey
        "39649811_plecak-nike-szkolny-sportowy-ba5405-010-b-r_after_time_decay"
        "10023965_wojna-swiatow-wells-vesper-twarda-oprawa_after_time_decay"
        "11097750_aldous-huxley-nowy-wspanialy-swiat-________after_time_decay"
        "11097750_stanislaw-lem-pamietnik-znaleziony-w-wannie-______after_time_decay"
        "6740469_pozdrawiam-moje-miasto-jozef-ratajczak-1968_after_time_decay"
        "6740469_nowy-korbut-bibliografia-literatury-polskiej-14-t_after_time_decay"
        "6740469_superkomputery-bez-tajemnic-david-loshin-1997_after_time_decay"
        "21424429_wojny-w-cyberprzestrzeni-guisnel-jean-znak_after_time_decay"
        "38901148_koniec-swieta-eisuke-nakazono_after_time_decay"
        "17346660_podstawy-informatyki-kolodziejczak-zielinski_after_time_decay"
        "6740469_urzadzenie-wewnetrzne-miast-wolnych-sejm-wielki_after_time_decay"
        "15528768_ddd-kompendium-wiedzy-vaughn-vernon_after_time_decay"
        "138008_matematyka-dyskretna-dla-informatykow_after_time_decay"
        "45702657_polski-fiat-125pfso-125p_after_time_decay"
        "43306282_unity-w-akcji-joe-hocking_after_time_decay"
        "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic_after_time_decay"
        "4276139_wallace-wang-internet-hakerzy-wirusy-ladnyegz_after_time_decay"
        "38901148_micro-prolog-keith-l-clark_after_time_decay"
        "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic_after_time_decay"
    }
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label=B
        style=filled
        color=lightgrey
        "39649811_plecak-nike-szkolny-sportowy-ba5405-010-b-r"
        "10023965_wojna-swiatow-wells-vesper-twarda-oprawa"
        "11097750_aldous-huxley-nowy-wspanialy-swiat-_______"
        "11097750_stanislaw-lem-pamietnik-znaleziony-w-wannie-_____"
        "6740469_pozdrawiam-moje-miasto-jozef-ratajczak-1968"
        "6740469_nowy-korbut-bibliografia-literatury-polskiej-14-t"
        "6740469_superkomputery-bez-tajemnic-david-loshin-1997"
        "21424429_wojny-w-cyberprzestrzeni-guisnel-jean-znak"
        "38901148_koniec-swieta-eisuke-nakazono"
        "17346660_podstawy-informatyki-kolodziejczak-zielinski"
        "6740469_urzadzenie-wewnetrzne-miast-wolnych-sejm-wielki"
        "6740469_superkomputery-bez-tajemnic-david-loshin-1997"
        "15528768_ddd-kompendium-wiedzy-vaughn-vernon"
        "138008_matematyka-dyskretna-dla-informatykow"
        "45702657_polski-fiat-125pfso-125p"
        "43306282_unity-w-akcji-joe-hocking"
        "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic"
        "4276139_wallace-wang-internet-hakerzy-wirusy-ladnyegz"
        "38901148_micro-prolog-keith-l-clark"
        "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic"
    }
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        label=A
        style=filled
        color=lightgrey
        7440293919
        7316212119
        7459478910
        7496246732
        7220215448
        7030101965
        7307790911
        7498596862
        7465256747
        7477936369
        6957447807
        7307790911
        7426854990
        7476186414
        7152887795
        7318012429
        7195398720
        7474847554
        6968472561
        7195397122
    }

    7440293919 -> "39649811_plecak-nike-szkolny-sportowy-ba5405-010-b-r" [label="2018-08-13T15:43:02.127" constraint=false]
    7316212119 -> "10023965_wojna-swiatow-wells-vesper-twarda-oprawa" [label="2018-08-11T23:54:52.740" constraint=false]
    7459478910 -> "11097750_aldous-huxley-nowy-wspanialy-swiat-_______" [label="2018-08-11T23:53:55.626" constraint=false]
    7496246732 -> "11097750_stanislaw-lem-pamietnik-znaleziony-w-wannie-_____" [label="2018-08-11T23:53:21.720" constraint=false]
    7220215448 -> "6740469_pozdrawiam-moje-miasto-jozef-ratajczak-1968" [label="2018-08-11T23:52:12.432" constraint=false]
    7030101965 -> "6740469_nowy-korbut-bibliografia-literatury-polskiej-14-t" [label="2018-08-11T23:52:08.754" constraint=false]
    7307790911 -> "6740469_superkomputery-bez-tajemnic-david-loshin-1997" [label="2018-08-11T23:52:03.990" constraint=false]
    7498596862 -> "21424429_wojny-w-cyberprzestrzeni-guisnel-jean-znak" [label="2018-08-11T23:05:59.337" constraint=false]
    7465256747 -> "38901148_koniec-swieta-eisuke-nakazono" [label="2018-08-11T23:04:31.077" constraint=false]
    7477936369 -> "17346660_podstawy-informatyki-kolodziejczak-zielinski" [label="2018-08-11T23:02:58.123" constraint=false]
    6957447807 -> "6740469_urzadzenie-wewnetrzne-miast-wolnych-sejm-wielki" [label="2018-08-11T23:01:58.357" constraint=false]
    7307790911 -> "6740469_superkomputery-bez-tajemnic-david-loshin-1997" [label="2018-08-11T23:01:42.263" constraint=false]
    7426854990 -> "15528768_ddd-kompendium-wiedzy-vaughn-vernon" [label="2018-08-11T22:55:01.702" constraint=false]
    7476186414 -> "138008_matematyka-dyskretna-dla-informatykow" [label="2018-08-11T22:54:26.675" constraint=false]
    7152887795 -> "45702657_polski-fiat-125pfso-125p" [label="2018-08-11T22:47:26.011" constraint=false]
    7318012429 -> "43306282_unity-w-akcji-joe-hocking" [label="2018-08-11T22:45:34.938" constraint=false]
    7195398720 -> "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic" [label="2018-08-11T22:44:44.794" constraint=false]
    7474847554 -> "4276139_wallace-wang-internet-hakerzy-wirusy-ladnyegz" [label="2018-08-11T22:42:30.278" constraint=false]
    6968472561 -> "38901148_micro-prolog-keith-l-clark" [label="2018-08-11T22:41:27.522" constraint=false]
    7195397122 -> "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic" [label="2018-08-11T22:39:47.893" constraint=false]
    "39649811_plecak-nike-szkolny-sportowy-ba5405-010-b-r" -> "39649811_plecak-nike-szkolny-sportowy-ba5405-010-b-r_after_time_decay" [label=0.8711024820449741 constraint=false]
    "10023965_wojna-swiatow-wells-vesper-twarda-oprawa" -> "10023965_wojna-swiatow-wells-vesper-twarda-oprawa_after_time_decay" [label=0.7220784976320539 constraint=false]
    "11097750_aldous-huxley-nowy-wspanialy-swiat-_______" -> "11097750_aldous-huxley-nowy-wspanialy-swiat-________after_time_decay" [label=0.7220292630457892 constraint=false]
    "11097750_stanislaw-lem-pamietnik-znaleziony-w-wannie-_____" -> "11097750_stanislaw-lem-pamietnik-znaleziony-w-wannie-______after_time_decay" [label=0.7220000378705059 constraint=false]
    "6740469_pozdrawiam-moje-miasto-jozef-ratajczak-1968" -> "6740469_pozdrawiam-moje-miasto-jozef-ratajczak-1968_after_time_decay" [label=0.7219403226503834 constraint=false]
    "6740469_nowy-korbut-bibliografia-literatury-polskiej-14-t" -> "6740469_nowy-korbut-bibliografia-literatury-polskiej-14-t_after_time_decay" [label=0.72193715306945 constraint=false]
    "6740469_superkomputery-bez-tajemnic-david-loshin-1997" -> "6740469_superkomputery-bez-tajemnic-david-loshin-1997_after_time_decay" [label=0.7219330476524938 constraint=false]
    "21424429_wojny-w-cyberprzestrzeni-guisnel-jean-znak" -> "21424429_wojny-w-cyberprzestrzeni-guisnel-jean-znak_after_time_decay" [label=0.7195584388992393 constraint=false]
    "38901148_koniec-swieta-eisuke-nakazono" -> "38901148_koniec-swieta-eisuke-nakazono_after_time_decay" [label=0.7194828881206028 constraint=false]
    "17346660_podstawy-informatyki-kolodziejczak-zielinski" -> "17346660_podstawy-informatyki-kolodziejczak-zielinski_after_time_decay" [label=0.7194033364179696 constraint=false]
    "6740469_urzadzenie-wewnetrzne-miast-wolnych-sejm-wielki" -> "6740469_urzadzenie-wewnetrzne-miast-wolnych-sejm-wielki_after_time_decay" [label=0.7193521968901969 constraint=false]
    "15528768_ddd-kompendium-wiedzy-vaughn-vernon" -> "15528768_ddd-kompendium-wiedzy-vaughn-vernon_after_time_decay" [label=0.7189958827772579 constraint=false]
    "138008_matematyka-dyskretna-dla-informatykow" -> "138008_matematyka-dyskretna-dla-informatykow_after_time_decay" [label=0.7189659445411196 constraint=false]
    "45702657_polski-fiat-125pfso-125p" -> "45702657_polski-fiat-125pfso-125p_after_time_decay" [label=0.7186065898565137 constraint=false]
    "43306282_unity-w-akcji-joe-hocking" -> "43306282_unity-w-akcji-joe-hocking_after_time_decay" [label=0.7185117650305968 constraint=false]
    "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic" -> "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic_after_time_decay" [label=0.7184689644772201 constraint=false]
    "4276139_wallace-wang-internet-hakerzy-wirusy-ladnyegz" -> "4276139_wallace-wang-internet-hakerzy-wirusy-ladnyegz_after_time_decay" [label=0.7183541723056891 constraint=false]
    "38901148_micro-prolog-keith-l-clark" -> "38901148_micro-prolog-keith-l-clark_after_time_decay" [label=0.7183006310417779 constraint=false]
    "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic" -> "46889202_eng-victor-eijkhout-tex-by-topic_after_time_decay" [label=0.7182156473959604 constraint=false]
}
```

Comment: You may simply remove the `constraint=false` edge attributes... they prevent the ranking of the nodes

Comment: @marapet - this worked great! Thanks! :)